# How do DeleteFile and FindFirstFile interact?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a program that basically does this

```
while(1)
  FindFirstFile()
  if file found
    CreateFile()
    DeleteFile()
```

However, sometimes CreateFile reports ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, even though FindFirstFile found a file! Does DeleteFile guarantee that the file won't show up in directory listings after it returns?

Comment: So you're trying to open the file that `FindFirstFile` finds, and that sometimes fails?

Comment: Yes, essentially. It _seems_ that FindFirstFile finds a file that should have been previously DeleteFile:d.

Comment: Are you sure no other process/thread touches/deletes the file(s) in question?

Comment: I'm sure none of my threads touch the file. It may, however, get accessed by an anti-virus program, as @JonathanPotter mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be running into the issue described by Raymond Chen in [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/07/10347136.aspx).

Basically, `DeleteFile()` is "kind of" asynchronous - if the file you are deleting has any outstanding file handles on it, the file system simply marks the file as "to be deleted", but it doesn't actually disappear from the directory listing until the last open handle to it is closed - even though `DeleteFile` returns success.

Comment: Well the customer as Symantec installed with on-access anti-virus search activated, so this may indeed be the cause. It seems I _can't_ count on DeleteFile to remove the file for subsequent file listings, and I'll have to change my program to cope with that.